# Bootstrap dropdown menu - stay open / close

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have single links in bootstrap navbar (eq. news, about) as well as few dropdown (Music -> Bands, Releases etc.).

When viewing the page on mobile version, bootstrap closes his master dropdown menu when you press any of the links, which is ok when you press eq. News or About, but It's not good when you want to access some of the sub dropdowns.

I know there is

```
// Closes the Responsive Menu on Menu Item Click
$('.navbar-collapse ul li a').click(function() {
$('.navbar-toggle:visible').click();
});
```

which prevents Bootstrap's master dropdown to close when you press any link, but is there a way to:

Close when you press eq. News or About

Stay open when you press eq. Music

Close when you press links inside Music dropdown eq. Bands, Releases

?

Here is the navbar code:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-main-collapse">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">
                <!-- <i class="fa fa-music"></i>   -->PAGE TITLE
            </a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-left navbar-main-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!-- Hidden li included to remove active class from about link when scrolled up past about section -->
                <li class="hidden">
                    <a href="#page-top"></a>
                </li>


                                 <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#news">News</a>
                </li>


                                 <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>


                                                     <li class="dropdown">
                                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Music<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                      <li><a href="#">Bands</a></li>
                                       <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                          <li><a href="#">Releases</a></li>

                                        </ul>
                                     </li>




            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/kbj61Lq6/